# Data are always showing of one furnace in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on an sql query where i will give a date from which Month and year will be determined. Then the record will be selected from Lab_Analysis and Lab_CSAnalysis table of any Furnace and Product ID. For this i Did following

```
    Declare @Furnace varchar(50)='FUR-A'
    Declare @Product bigint=1
    Declare @sd date
    Declare @ed date
    Declare @Date date='02-02-2019'
    SET @sd=(SELECT DATEADD(s,1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@Date),0)))
    SET @ed=(SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@Date)+1,0)))

    ;WITH dates AS (
        SELECT @sd as theDate
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, theDate)
        FROM dates 
        WHERE DATEADD(day, 1, theDate) <= @ed
    )

    SELECT     DATEPART(dd, D.theDate) AS 'Day', ISNULL(LS.QtyMT, 0) AS QtyMt, ISNULL(SUM(L.Mn), 0) AS Mn, ISNULL(SUM(L.Si), 0) AS Si, ISNULL(SUM(L.P), 0) AS P, 
                  ISNULL(LS.Carbon, 0) AS C, ISNULL(LS.Sulphur, 0) AS S, ISNULL(SUM(L.MnO), 0) AS MnO, ISNULL(SUM(L.CaO), 0) AS CaO, ISNULL(SUM(L.AI2O3), 0) 
                  AS AI2O3, ISNULL(SUM(L.MgO), 0) AS MgO, ISNULL(SUM(L.Fe2O3), 0) AS Fe2O3, ISNULL(SUM(L.SiO2), 0) AS SiO2, ISNULL(SUM(L.Basicity), 0) AS Basicity
FROM         Lab_Product AS LP INNER JOIN
                  Lab_Analysis AS L ON LP.ID = L.Product RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                  dates AS D ON L.Date = theDate LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  Lab_CSAnalysis AS LS ON LS.Date = L.Date AND (LP.ID = 1 AND L.Furnace = @Furnace AND LS.Furnace=@Furnace)
GROUP BY D.theDate, LS.QtyMT, LS.Carbon, LS.Sulphur
```

Here i want to view Record of Furnace='A' and ProductID=1. Then the above query is correct Output. There is no Record in Other than Furnace 'A' and Product ID=1. But when i want to View records of Furnace 'B' then it is still showing records of Furnace 'A'. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

because of your filter on the left join. I made some changing over your query

```
Declare @Furnace varchar(50)='FUR-A'
    Declare @Product bigint=1
    Declare @sd date
    Declare @ed date
    Declare @Date date='02-02-2019'
    SET @sd=(SELECT DATEADD(s,1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@Date),0)))
    SET @ed=(SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@Date)+1,0)))

    ;WITH dates AS (
        SELECT @sd as theDate
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, theDate)
        FROM dates 
        WHERE DATEADD(day, 1, theDate) <= @ed
    )

SELECT  DATEPART(dd, D.theDate) AS 'Day', 
        ISNULL(LS.QtyMT, 0) AS QtyMt, 
        ISNULL(SUM(L.Mn), 0) AS Mn, 
        ISNULL(SUM(L.Si), 0) AS Si, 
        ISNULL(SUM(L.P), 0) AS P, 
        ISNULL(LS.Carbon, 0) AS C, 
        ISNULL(LS.Sulphur, 0) AS S, 
        ISNULL(SUM(L.MnO), 0) AS MnO, 
        ISNULL(SUM(L.CaO), 0) AS CaO, 
        ISNULL(SUM(L.AI2O3), 0) AS AI2O3, 
        ISNULL(SUM(L.MgO), 0) AS MgO, 
        ISNULL(SUM(L.Fe2O3), 0) AS Fe2O3, 
        ISNULL(SUM(L.SiO2), 0) AS SiO2, 
        ISNULL(SUM(L.Basicity), 0) AS Basicity
FROM 
    dates 
    INNER JOIN Lab_Analysis AS L ON L.Date = dates.theDate AND L.Furnace = @Furnace
    LEFT JOIN Lab_Product AS LP ON LP.ID = L.Product AND LP.ID = 1 
    LEFT JOIN Lab_CSAnalysis AS LS ON LS.Date = L.Date AND (L.Furnace = LS.Furnace)
GROUP BY 
    D.theDate, LS.QtyMT, LS.Carbon, LS.Sulphur
```

Comment: It is showing records of those dates on which records are inserted. If there is no any record found on any date of any month then it should show 0.

Comment: I made some changing.

Comment: Your above query is still showing records if there is no record in any furnace as it showing 0 on all days of given month

Comment: don't you want to see the days which has no records?

Comment: If there is not any record in any specific Furnace then no record should show. But it still showing records and all days it is showing 0.

Comment: I changed left join to inner. Now, it shouldn't return.